# Getting count(column) as well as a specific row in each group

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by, count

I am working with SQL Server 2012.

I want to get the count of column as well as the rows with specific condition in each group.

The query I have in mind looks something like this:

```
select count(column1), (column2 where column2 contains 'page1')
group by column1
```

I know that the above query isn't correct but I want to show the idea.

**Sample data**

```
column1   column2 
-------  --------
x1       'temp/page1_l'
x1       'temp/page2_f'
x2       'temp/page2_d'
x2       'temp/page1_k'
x2       'temp/page2_e'
```

**Expected output**

```
count(column1)  column2 
--------------  --------------
2               'temp/page1_l'
3               'temp/page1_k'
```

How can I achieve that output?

Comment: Can you explain why it's these specific rows you want (`page1_l` and `page1_k`)? In this simple example (only five rows), it is easy to see that they are the *only* ones with `page1` in the string. But what if `x1` had `page1_l` and `page1_m`?

Comment: each group must  have only one string that contain page1

Comment: Great! How is that enforced?

Comment: The data I work on have this rule ,only one row per group have  string 'page1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #d ( column1 char(2), column2 varchar(32) );

INSERT #d (column1, column2) 
   VALUES ('x1',    'temp/page1_l'),
          ('x1',    'temp/page2_f'),
          ('x2',    'temp/page2_d'),
          ('x2',    'temp/page1_k'),
          ('x2',    'temp/page2_e');
```

One way to solve it is by taking the count separately:

```
;WITH agg AS
(
  SELECT column1, col1count = COUNT(*)
    FROM #d 
    GROUP BY column1
)
SELECT [count(column1)] = agg.col1count, filt.column2
  FROM agg INNER JOIN #d AS filt
    ON agg.column1 = filt.column1
  WHERE filt.column2 LIKE '%page1[_]%';
```

Or slightly differently:

```
;WITH d AS
(
  SELECT column1, column2, 
    column1count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY column1)
  FROM #d
)
SELECT [count(column1)] = column1count, column2 
  FROM d
  WHERE column2 LIKE '%page1[_]%';
```

Another is along the lines of Rob's suggestion:

```
SELECT [count(column1)] = COUNT(column1),
    column2 = MIN(CASE WHEN column2 LIKE '%page1[_]%' THEN column2 END)
  FROM #d 
  GROUP BY column1;
```

Answer (score 4):

For the `(column2 where column2 contains 'page1')` expression, try something like:

```
MAX(CASE WHEN Column2 LIKE '%page1%' THEN Column2 END)
```

...but I'm not sure what you expect if you have multiple rows with "page1" per column1.

Comment: And note that `LIKE '%page1%' ` will count page1 but also page11, page100, page101, etc.

Comment: Sure. The question was just looking for that string...

Comment: I didn't mean to criticize your answer, only note for the OP.

Comment: please @RobFarley I want to count on column1 as in the output

Comment: You can still put `count(column1)`

Comment: @RobFarley I need count on column1 and applying the condition on column2

Comment: @Elsayed: You've got the `count(column1)` bit right (you could also use `count(*)` instead, there'd be no difference in this case), and the expression for `column2` is in this answer – what else do you expect?